# We are unable to restore the nuget packages used in the solution when trying to build with MsBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, nuget

We are unable to restore the Nuget packages used in the solution file with Ms Build

Enviroment
Asp.Net solution
Visual Studio 2015

Comment: We need more details. What is the error message? What is printed to the log?

Comment: we go project folder we run the commands to command prompt                                                                       1)      call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"                                                                                                     2)MBUILD -t:nuget restore              we run these commands for build the application and restore the packages

Comment: we getting the error:MSBuild:error MSB1009: project file does not exist. switch :restore

Answer (score 1):

> We are unable to restore the nuget packages used in the solution when trying to build with MsBuild

That is correct behavior for MSBuild. Because restored NuGet package is completed by **NuGet** instead of MSBuild.

When you build in the Visual Studio, there are two options about nuget package management:

`Tools`->`NuGet Package Manager`->`Package Manager Settings`->`General`:

[image]

With those two options, Visual Studio will restore nuget package automatically when you build the project/solution.

**But** this feature is not built into MSBuild in Visual Studio 2015, so you could not restore the Nuget packages used in the solution file with MSBuild.

To restore the nuget package with command line, you could use nuget CLI to restore it:

- Download the [nuget CLI](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.9.3/nuget.exe) from the nuget.org.
- Set this nuget.exe on your local.
- Open Command prompt windows, switch the path to where nuget exists.
- Use the command line `nuget.exe restore "YourSolution.sln"`

Check [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-restore) for some details.

**Update for your comments:**

> 2)MBUILD -t:nuget restore we run these commands for build the
>   application and restore the packages

The MSBuild restore target **works only** for projects using the **PackageReference** format. It does not work for projects using the `packages.config` format; use nuget restore instead.

Since you are using Visual Studio 2015, you could not use the `PackageReference`, which is a product of Visual Studio 2017. So you have to use nuget restore.

Check the document: [restore target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target).

Hope this helps.